# Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown

Tags: mysql, ibatis, ibatis.net

I have an application which throws "Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException'". Which reduces the performance of the server,the CPU usage was around 95%.
    I dont know the reason why this problem is occuring ....
    can any one pls tell wats the reason for the error and how can i sort it out????

This is my stack trace:

```
Message
Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.

Source
MySql.Data

Stack
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameterCollection..ctor() at
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand..ctor() at
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.CreateDbCommand() at 
System.Data.Common.DbConnection.System.Data.IDbConnection.CreateCommand() at 
IBatisNet.Common.DbProvider.CreateDataParameter() at 
IBatisNet.DataMapper.SqlMapSession.CreateDataParameter() at   
IBatisNet.DataMapper.Configuration.Statements.PreparedStatementFactory.CreateParametersForTextCommand() at IBatisNet.DataMapper
```

Comment: the problem is most likely in the application, you are running, not mysql server. provide some details on the application and you will get a clearer answer..

Comment: I have an video upload service application where they can view live event videos.I am displaying a message for the user every 30 seconds once which will be retreived from the data base and displayed to the user for 30 seconds once a server request is sent.When there are more number of users large number of request is sent 30seconds once which causes this exception...can u pls tell wats the problem is???